# Gráfico min-máx con ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot

Tengo un data.frame similar a esto:

```
grupo   media   min     max
gr1     2.427   2.116   2.790
gr2     0.786   0.694   0.889
gr3     1.474   1.284   1.700
```

Quiero hacer un gráfico en el que en el eje y esté el grupo y en el eje x tenga una línea entre min y max y me aparezca un punto en el valor de la media. Además, necesito una línea vertical en el valor 1 del eje x.

Gracias!

Comment: Pon el código que has intentado hacer, de nada!

Comment: Hola, @javdromero
La cuestión era esa, no había utilizado ningún código porque no sabía hacerlo. Pero ya está. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al final conseguí utilizar el siguiente código y funcionó.

```
grafica <- ggplot(df2) + 
             geom_segment(aes(x = min, xend = sup, y = grupo, yend = grupo)) + 
             geom_point(aes(x = media, y = grupo)) +
             geom_vline(xintercept = 1)
```